# Infinispan 8 - cache.clear() - How to understand the javadoc correctly?

Tags: java, caching, infinispan

In infinispan 8.2.5.Final I have one use case where I want to evict/clear all entries from the cache. I am calling cache.clear(). The Javadoc says:

> void org.infinispan.Cache.clear()
>
> Removes all mappings from the cache.
>
> Note: This should never be invoked in production unless you can
>   guarantee **no other invocations are ran concurrently**.
>
> If the cache is transactional, it will not interact with the
>   transaction.
>
> Specified by: clear() in Map

Does it mean "no other invocations of cache.clear()"? Or does it mean "no other invocations of the underlying cache at all"? So no cache.put and cache.get concurrently?

Its a common use case to clear the cache (new data is coming in). Did I use the wrong method? Are there other ways to evict all items from an infinispan cache?

Edit:
I am running my cache in invalidation mode. Does the clear() operation invalidate all entries in all nodes or just in the local node?

Comment: Is there an actual problem?  Did you get an error?

Comment: no error as it is not in production yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means "no other write operation can be run". The `clear()` may corrupt the concurrent write operation (it can be applied in some nodes, but missing in another) since it doesn't try to acquire any locking.

If you are worried about concurrent writes, you can use the `stream()` or the `iterator()`. As an example:

```
cache.keySet().stream().forEach(BasicCache::remove);
```

or

```
for (Iterator<K> it = cache.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    it.next();
    it.remove();
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for this insight. As you say "nodes": I am running my cache in invalidation mode. Does the clear() operation invalidate all entries in all nodes or just in the local node. (added this also to my original question)

Comment: the clear() goes to all nodes. You can use the CACHE_MODE_LOCAL flag to force it to the local node. 
example: cache.getAdvancedCache().withFlags(CACHE_MODE_LOCAL).clear()

Note that the iterator/stream iterate in all the nodes. You can use the same flag to iterate local only keys.